# How to keep floating labels floating after input. Pure CSS

Tags: html, forms, css

I've successfully floated labels above form input fields when focused, but I'm stumped on how to keep the labels floating if text is entered into the field and un-focused.

There are tons of pure CSS examples online but none are clear to me what is keeping a filled field label floating.  I'm sure it fairly easy but I'm fairly new to this.

EDIT: I need to do this without using the "required" method mentioned in the comments below.  My form is a combination of required and non-required fields.

Here is one of many examples I've found:
http://codepen.io/atunnecliffe/pen/gpKzQw

Here is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yzzxrsnn/1/

Many thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
<textarea maxlength="280" class="form-textarea"></textarea>
<label class="form-label" alt='Search Map' placeholder='Search Map'>Text Area</label>
<br>
<input type='text'  class="form-input" placeholder="" onclick='this.value = "";'>
<label class="form-label" alt='Search Map' placeholder='Search Map'>Text</label>
<br>
<select class="form-input" >
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden></option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
</select>
<label class="form-label" for="name">Select</label>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.form-input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
  resize: none;
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
  background:#fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
}

.form-input:focus {
  border-color: #00bafa;
}

.form-input + .form-label {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
  margin:  0 0 0 15px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-top: -43px;
    margin-bottom: 43px;
  transition: transform 1s;

}

.form-label {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.form-input:focus + .form-label {
  transform: translateY(-38px);
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bafa;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.form-textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
  resize: none;
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
  background:#fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
}

.form-textarea:focus {
  border-color: #00bafa;
}

.form-textarea + .form-label {
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
  margin:  0 0 0 15px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-top: -145px;
    margin-bottom: 145px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.form-textarea:focus + .form-label {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bafa;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.form-textarea + .form-label:before {
  transform: translateY(-38px);
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bafa;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using jquery. Using jquery we can add class to a input and it's label if the value of that input is bigger than 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $input = $('.form-input');

    $input.focusout(function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('input-focus');
            $(this).next('.form-label').addClass('input-focus-label');
        }
        else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-focus');
            $(this).next('.form-label').removeClass('input-focus-label');

        }
    });
});
```

and some css

```
.input-focus-label{
    transform: translateY(-38px);
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bafa;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.input-focus{
    border-color: #00bafa;
}
```

Here is a example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzzxrsnn/2/).Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I'm coming to realize now that there is no way of doing this in Pure CSS without using the "required" attribute. I've gone this method.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: Strange thing.  I was making edits on the site and deleted the Java script portion of your solution on accident and it still works.  Is there any particular case when the javascript comes into play?

Comment: I think your site cached in your browser. Try clearing cache and check it still works.

Comment: You're right.  I see now that the labels elevate but once the focus is off the field they fall again even though I types inside them.

Comment: Yep you need javascript code to make that work. So you need to add javascript part back.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `required` for your input elements, you can take advantage of `:valid` selector:

```css
        .form-input {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 400px;
            height: 55px;
            margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
            padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
            resize: none;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            background: transparent;
            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #000;
            background: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
            -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
            transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
        }

            .form-input:focus {
                border-color: #00bafa;
            }

            .form-input + .form-label {
                display: block;
                pointer-events: none;
                margin: 0 0 0 15px;
                line-height: 0px;
                margin-top: -43px;
                margin-bottom: 43px;
                transition: transform 1s;
            }

        .form-label {
            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #ccc;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .form-input:focus + .form-label, .form-input:valid + .input-label, .form-input:valid + .dropdown-label {
            transform: translateY(-38px);
            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #00bafa;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .form-textarea {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 400px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
            padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
            resize: none;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            background: transparent;
            font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #000;
            background: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
            -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
            transition: border-color ease-in-out .5s,box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
        }

            .form-textarea:focus {
                border-color: #00bafa;
            }

            .form-textarea + .form-label {
                display: block;
                pointer-events: none;
                margin: 0 0 0 15px;
                line-height: 0px;
                margin-top: -145px;
                margin-bottom: 145px;
                transition: transform 1s;
            }

            .form-textarea:focus + .form-label, .form-textarea:valid + .textarea-label {
                transform: translateY(-38px);
                font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #00bafa;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            .form-textarea + .form-label:before {
                transform: translateY(-38px);
                pointer-events: none;
                font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #00bafa;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
```

```html
    <fieldset class="form-field">
        <textarea maxlength="280" class="form-textarea" required></textarea>
        <label class="form-label textarea-label" alt='Search Map' placeholder='Search Map'>Text Area</label>
        <br>
        <input type='text' class="form-input" placeholder="" onclick='this.value = "";' required>
        <label class="form-label input-label" alt='Search Map' placeholder='Search Map'>Text</label>
        <br>
        <select class="form-input" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden></option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <label class="form-label dropdown-label" for="name">Select</label>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I should have mentioned that my site currently uses the "Required" method but I'm trying to get away from using it.  It's messing up forms that contain non-required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty [edit on your fiddle](http://codepen.io/kevint/pen/VmbzvL)

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
<input type='text'  class="form-input" placeholder=""  required onclick='this.value = "";'>
<label class="form-label" alt='Search Map' placeholder='Search Map'>Text</label>
</fieldset>
```

And for the CSS:

```
.form-input:focus + .form-label,
.form-input:valid + .form-label {
transform: translateY(-38px);
font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', Arial, sans-serif;
color: #00bafa;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Basically, take advantage of `:valid` to coincide with `:focus` by adding `required` to your fields